# problema al llamar el método de php desde angular

Tags: php

lo que quiero hacer es llamar al método de php desde angular js
este es mi codigo de angularjs:

```
$scope.registrar = function(){
    $http.post("estudiante.php")
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("guardado exitosamente")
    })
};
```

y esto es lo que tengo en el php:

```html
<?php 
echo 'DATOS INSERTADOS CORRECTAMENTE A LA BBDD'; 
?>
```

bueno no me tira error pero tampoco me muestra el mensaje ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto. Tienes un problema con las dichosas ";" no te preocupes, al principio siempre pasa cuando aprendes a utilizar un framework nuevo

```js
$scope.registrar = function(){
    $http.post("estudiante.php")
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("guardado exitosamente")
    });
}
```

Te dejo un link muy interesante sobre el [Php + Angular](http://www.albertcoronado.com/2014/06/17/ejemplo-de-uso-de-angularjs-php/)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con `.then`, los `success` y `error` estan obsoletos

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'file.php'

}).then(function success(response) {
    console.log(response)
}, function error(response) {
    /* Error llamada */
    console.log(response);
});
```